# match() in body returns odd result

Tags: javascript, html, regex, match

I am trying to use `RegExp` in `Javascript` (specifically the `match` function) to find the occurrence of a sentence and a word within that sentence in the HTML body. The following is some pseudo-code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="hello">

<p id="demo">Click the button to display the matches.</p>

<div> <input type="button" value="search" onclick="myFunction('<p id=&quot;demo&quot;>Click the button to display the matches', 'button')" />Try it </div>

<script>
function myFunction(sentence, word)
{
//var str="The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
//var toMatch = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
var r = new RegExp(word, 'g');
var oldHTML = document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML;
var n=oldHTML.match(r);
alert("no. of matches = " + n.length);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above HTML, there is only one occurrence of the sentence and one word 'button', yet the  number of searches = 4 and `n = button,button,button,button`.

My questions:
1. Why does that RegExp result in 4 searches?
2. How can I search the HTML `body` section such that the answer I get is correct?

Comment: #1 `<p id="demo">Click the button`, #2 `<input type="button"`, #3 `quot;>Click the button`, #4 `, 'button')`

Comment: you are correctly getting the response as 4. There are 4 occurences of the word button.
1. >Click the button
2. input type="button"
3. Click the button
4. , 'button')

Comment: @Andreas: got it. If I were to search for the sentence instead, I get one match. How can I get the start index of the match?

Comment: First occurance of `button` in the visible text? `sentence.indexOf(word)` or `(oldHTML.innerText || oldHTML.textContent).indexOf(word)` for the visible text in `<body id="hello">`

Answer (score 0):

1. As others already stated, you get 4 occurances, since you search through whole html markup, not just user-visible text.
2. Use `innerText` property instead of `innerHTML` to get better results.

Comment: Is there any function in Javascript that would allow me to search only user-visible text? The innerText property, applied on the body tag would allow me to do that?

Comment: More or less: yes. Use the innerText to get the text of the given element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's text function to get the text of your body element, and search from it.

```
e.g 
bodyElement = $("body");
bodyText = bodyElement.text();
```